# Local and Remote MongoDB

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

Is it possible to have a local and a remote MongoDB and if the user is offline to use the local database and if he is online the local changes are merged in the remote database?

Comment: Simply put - no. If one cannot guarantee it is the primary server (in replicaset), then they will become SECONDARY which will only serve reads. If you were to somehow write to both databases at the same time (local and remote), then when they become reconnected, whichever one had the newest data would take PRIMARY, and any writes on the older would would be rolled back.

Comment: I guess I have to switch to CouchDB.